# MMA8452Q INT1/2 drive circuitry

Tags: accelerometer

I'm struggling to find any information on how the interrupt outputs on the [MMA8452Q](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMA8452Q.pdf) accelerometer are driven. I need to know whether they're open-drain or push-pull for example. I've poured through Google and can't find anything pertaining to how the outputs are driven.

How are the INT outputs being driven on the MMA8452Q accelerometer?

Answer (score 2):

They are push-pull, looks like LVCMOS or equivalent. The test conditions were for 500uA, it would be advisable to pull less current than the test conditions.

[image]
Source: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMA8452Q.pdf

Comment: Beat me by 20 sec

Comment: Gotta be quick!

Comment: I'd feel bad accepting one of your answers over the other as you both helped! Cheers guys!

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet table implies that they are driven both high and low.

[image]